# Open Source IP/Network load balancer

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I've got a need to load balance two firewalls. Can I use NGINX or HAProxy to do IP load balancing, i.e. forward all IP traffic regardless of port or protocol to the backend server(fw)? Firewall has a native HA option, but not supported in the desired environment (Palo in Azure)

If not, any other open source recommendations?

Comment: Should that not be solved by hardware instead of software? A router that supports IP SLA (like a Cisco 800) between the firewalls and your LAN.

Comment: Azure, i.e. no HW & Azure LB only TCP